# Does the initial java download have to reside in the same file as subsequent jdks that I download?

Tags: java

I had trouble running eclipse and was getting a message that the virtual machine could not be created. After multiple attempts at fixing my eclipse.ini file with an appropriate path, I finally deleted java and references to it before downloading it all again. While I was redownloading, I noticed that my initial java download went in this path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_251 . I then downloaded the latest jdk which is now stored in this path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1 . Eclipse is currently working, however I am being cautious as the first time I seemed to have found a solution, my problems started again a day or two later. I just want to know if it matters whether java and jdk/jre's are in the same path/folder and why.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter where the JDK is installed to.

It is just important to add the folder to your PATH, so that java-commands will be recognized by a CLI. This will also define which JDK is being used to run Eclipse (the first Java instance found is being used; can also be overridden by defining it in eclipse.ini).

Also you should point Eclipse itself to the correct folder (Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs).
This sets the JDK that is used to run the java-project from Eclipse.

However, the first time you apparently installed a 32-bit JDK, the second time a 64-bit JDK, judging by the directories you listed.
64-bit Eclipse-instances will not work with a 32-bit JDK.

Comment: Note that the preferences in *Java -> Installed JREs* do not affect the JRE that is used to run Eclipse itself, which this question seems to be about. That part of this answer seems irrelevant to the question. The preferences in *Java -> Installed JREs* only affect which JREs that are used to debug applications from within Eclipse.

Comment: @Lii Thanks for pointing that out, I amended the answer to include a distinction between JDK used for running Eclipse project and JDK used for running Eclipse itself.

Comment: Can you please expand on your first paragraph? How can I add it to my path?

Comment: @darkdreder For Windows: Open Start Search, type in "env" and choose “Edit the system environment variables”. Click the “Environment Variables…” button, then under the “System Variables” section (the lower half), find the row with “Path” in the first column, and click edit. The “Edit environment variable” UI will appear. Here, you can click “New” and type in the new path you want to add (the directory you installed the latest JDK to, so probably "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1")

Comment: Also restart your PC to make sure the PATH-changes take effect.